# Why Does MySql LEFT OUTER JOIN Return 20x more rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Okay, I've getting 400,816 rows returned on the following LEFT OUTER JOIN query

```
SELECT 
    `inventory`.`inventory_id`,
    `inventory`.`inventory_units_in_stock`,
    `inventory`.`sire_name`,
    `inventory`.`owner_id`,
    `inventory`.`facility`,
    `inventory`.`breed`,
    `inventory`.`cane_number`,
    `inventory`.`collection_date`,
    `inventory`.`inventory_temporary_location`,
    `inventory`.`inventory_tank`,
    `inventory`.`inventory_bay`,
    `inventory`.`inventory_canister`,
    `inventory`.`inventory_remarks`,
    `inventory`.`inventory_update`,
    `inventory`.`inventory_create`,
    `inventory`.`inventory_user_update`,
    `inventory`.`inventory_user_create`,
    `collections`.`collectionId`
FROM `inventory`
LEFT JOIN
    `collections` ON Date(`collections`.`collection_date`) = Date(`inventory`.`collection_date`)
```

The inventory table has 20,867 records, the collections table has 15,326 records. So how is the above query returning 400,816 records?

collection_date in both inventory and collections table is a MySql datatype = DATE. I wrapped both in Date() during the ON because I was getting the same query results without it and I was hoping it was due to invalid dates comparisons.

The goal is I'm moving data to a new database. I didn't create the old one but the original database designer configured their queries to check dates between these two tables. Yes, there can be multiple records having the same collection date in the inventory table, but the inventory is the actual inventory on hand.

This is a sample of data in the collections table, collection_date is the 2045-04-16 (don't ask, not my data)...

```
2152   271   AN   3137   2045-04-16    6972   172   XX   ok+   50   3   45   2015-04-20 08:14:02   2015-04-20 03:14:01   NULL   jenna
 701   237   AN   2996   2017-07-21   18996    25   IO   ISR    0   0    0   2017-07-21 10:51:48   2017-07-21 05:51:47   NULL   michael
5633   271   AN   3817   2017-07-20   19004    47   R    ok    50   3    8   2017-07-21 11:11:52   2017-07-21 06:11:52   NULL   Megan
5634   271   AN   3818   2017-07-20   19002    52   M    ok    45   3    8   2017-07-21 11:05:06   2017-07-21 06:05:06   NULL   Megan
```

Below is a sample of data in the inventory table, the 1901-04-29 is the inventory collection date. Again don't ask about the date, not my data I'm simply trying to move it to a new system.

```
32711   159   5L Blazin View 1635-235x   10874   154   AR    207   1901-04-29   13   1    2   2014-02-10 16:04:59   2014-02-10 04:04:59   NULL, 
32712   114   5L Blazin View 1635-235x   10874   154   AR    207   1901-04-30   13   1   20   2014-02-10 16:04:59   2014-02-10 04:04:59   NULL, 
32713   121   5L Blazin View 1635-235x   10874   154   AR    207   1901-05-01   13   1   25   2014-02-10 16:04:59   2014-02-10 04:04:59   NULL, 
32714   130   5L Destination 893-6215    10874    99   AR   5602   1902-01-27    8   1   26   2016-04-21 06:24:31   2014-02-10 04:04:59   karla   
32715    45   5L Hobo Design 273-7047    10874    99   AR   6248   1900-07-31    5   1   34   2014-02-10 16:04:59   2014-02-10 04:04:59   NULL, 
32716    50   5L Hobo Design 273-7047    10874    99   AR   6248   1902-01-28    6   4   14   2014-02-10 16:04:59   2014-02-10 04:04:59   NULL, 
32717     1   5L Norse Design 673-5035   10874    75   AR    342   1900-05-31    7   1    2   2014-02-10 16:04:59   2014-02-10 04:04:59   NULL,
```

Any insight how to stop the exponential return results. I do understand a left outer join can return more rows than what is in the left table, but I am not aware where this type join can return 20x more records than found in the largest number of records in a table. These results greatly exceed the combined total of rows in both tables which is around 36k.

Expected results is to simply join the new collections.collectionId to the inventory table so I can remove the date relationship in the current system. I'm hoping to return the 20,867 inventory records with an associated collectionId.

Comment: You want 20,867 result rows, one per inventory record. As we can see, there are (at least) two collection records for 2017-07-20. So which one shall be picked for an inventory record with that date? So far both records get joined, but you only want one of them. Which? What is the rule you want applied here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you join your tables using only the date filed, if you have 5 records in the tableA with the date X and 20 records in the tableB with the same date X. the result of your query will be 5 x 20 = 100

the use of the date() function returns the date part of a date or datetime expression.

i'll try to explay using an example:

```
table_A
--------
nameA, date
a1, 2017-11-01
a2, 2017-11-01

table_B
-------
nameB, date
b1, 2017-11-01
b2, 2017-11-01
```

if you join A on B using a similar join used in your query:

> select nameA,nameB from table_A left join table_B on Date(table_A) =
>   Date(table_B)

```
you will have:
a1, b1 -> Date(2017-11-01) is equal to Date(2017-11-01)
a1, b2 -> Date(2017-11-01) is equal to Date(2017-11-01)
a2, b1 -> Date(2017-11-01) is equal to Date(2017-11-01)
a2, b2 -> Date(2017-11-01) is equal to Date(2017-11-01)
```

Please keep in mind that using the Date() formula in your join, your database engine is forced to not use indexes. Then this is a really poor and slow way to query your data.

Comment: I can see and understand your explanation, but to do this they would be datetime columns and they are date columns. As I said in my question I tried both inventory.collection_date = collections.collection_date prior to Date(inventory.collection_date) = Date(collections.collection_date) and still returned 400k+ rows... Unless your indicating the join is working outside of dates in the on clause and using the additional date fields?

Comment: if you join your tables using only the date filed, if you have 5 records in the tableA with the date X and 20 records in the tableB with the same date X. the result of your query will be 5 x 20 = 100 rows

Comment: i just updated my answer, i hope to be more clear now :-)

Comment: Very good explanation. @aallord: As you see, it all depends on the join criteria. The maximum number of rows you could get with your query would be 20,867 x 15,326 = 319,807,642 in case all dates where the same. As this is not the case, you get somthing between 20,867 and 319,807,642 rows depending on how many dates match. You are probably missing criteria, something else that links inventory and collection, e.g. a product number, the owner, the facility, the cane number, ...

Comment: The light came on sometime around 1:00.. The original table design combined (facility, breed, cane number and collection date) to form the primary key... So I'm missing those in my join... Thanks everyone, @Thorsten Kettner I was not aware of the exponential results so great explanation there.